# Is there any SQL client for hive

Tags: hive

I want to do table comparison in Hive. It is very hard to do that in the console. Is there any client tool to view the Hive query results such as `SQL Developer`

Comment: Do you want to view only the meta data (schema, table's structure, column type, etc) or includes the actual data which calculated by MapReduce?

Comment: @ChrisZheng Sorry for late response.I am trying to look at the data calculated by mapreduce. Yes I would like to see the column names in the output.

Comment: I wrote a python script using hive thrift to fetch the informations of databases, tables, and columns from hive database, and put them in a webpage for viewing. If you want to see the column name of the output,  this way seems can't work. Have you try what I suggested in the answer?

Comment: @ChrisZheng I am trying out this option but as my Hive is on remote server, its somehow giving me errors. I am checking with server team lets see what comes out.

Comment: There is a free tool called HIVEDEVELOPER http://stratapps.com/, You can connect to Hive using HiveDeveloper tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both SQL Dev and Squirrel SQL works good and also the setup is quite easy in Squirrel SQL. The same is true for SQL Dev also. For those who are looking for a out of box solution, please also check Beeswex provided by Cloudera https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/HUE/Beeswax#Beeswax-BeeswaxandHiveInstallationandConfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

SQL developer supports other types of databases, other than Oracle.  You just need the jdbc driver for hive, and configure that in SQL Developer.

I don't have it in front of me, but if I remember, you go to Tools->Preferences->Third Party JDBC Drivers, and then add the Hive JDBC driver.  I have had some difficulty getting this to work, esp. in the Linux client.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I see one [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1368) of hive which is about Hive JDBC integration with SQuirrel SQL Client.

With it, you can browse the hive table's structure (table's column and their data type) and SQL query through Squirrel SQL client.

Maybe you can look into it to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I actually needed something like this recently. I looked around and came up with this: http://stratapps.com/HiveSQL.php

The screenshot there is not it... I think it shows the history of the queries, but the app itself contains an area where it shows the table of the Hive query results and you can export it to excel to do the comparison there. Hope that helps!